# Standalone PWA slow performance on iOS 16

Tags: ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a React PWA and I'm having some performance issues only when running in standalone mode; it runs fine in Safari. This only happened on iOS 16 (betas and the official release).

In particular, the problem is that when I click on two buttons in quick succession only the first click works.

Sorry, I know this is kind of a bad question but I'm really lost here. The difference in performance between the browser and the standalone mode makes no sense to me.